# Find the optimal dividing line

Tags: mathematics, geometry, optimization

Consider the following grid of numbers:

[image]

In machine readable form:

```
[[-3  2  2  2 -1  2  0  1  2 -1]
 [ 0  1 -2 -1 -1  1  3  3  1  3]
 [ 1 -3  0 -1  1  2  2 -2  0  3]
 [-1  0  1 -2  0  2  2 -2 -3  2]
 [-3  0 -3  1 -2  1 -3  3  0 -3]
 [-2 -1  0  2  1  3  1  2  2 -1]
 [ 0  3  1  0  1 -1 -1  2  2  2]
 [-2 -3  1  2 -1  3  3 -1 -1  2]
 [ 2  1  3  2  0  2 -1  1  2 -1]
 [-1  3 -2 -1  1  1 -2  1  2 -1]]
```

If you draw a straight line from one side to another of the grid, your score is the sum of all the numbers in squares where the middle (shown with blue dots) is on the side of the line including the top left corner of the grid.  You are not allowed to start or end the line exactly in the top left corner.

What is the optimal line? You are aiming to maximize the score.

Comment: would. be nice to provide text/sheet version.

Comment: @Oray I made an addition. Is that better?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sum of all the numbers in the grid is 38.

Color-coding the grid allows us to easily see favorable/unfavorable portions of the grid:

[image]

Our goal is then to remove the least favorable portion with a single straight cut.

I believe this may be optimal:

> Removing a sum of -7 leaves us with a sum of 45.
>  [image]

Comment: A very nice answer. How did you draw the color coded grid?

Comment: @Simd I just used the bucket tool (flood fill) in Paint

Comment: I confirmed optimality via integer linear programming.

Comment: @RobPratt Could you add the ilp you used? I would be interested

Answer (score 3):

The maximum is

> 45,

achieved, for example, by

> [image]

I solved the problem via mixed integer linear programming as follows.  Let $a_{ij}$ be the given value in cell $(i,j)$.  Let $\epsilon>0$ be a small constant tolerance.
Let decision variables $\alpha$ and $\beta$ define the line $\alpha i + \beta j = 1$. Let binary decision variable $x_{ij}$ indicate whether cell $(i,j)$ is selected.  The problem is to maximize $\sum_{i,j} a_{ij} x_{ij}$ subject to linear constraints
\begin{align}
x_{0,0} &= 1 \tag1\label1 \\
\alpha i + \beta j - 1 + \epsilon &\le M(1-x_{ij}) &&\text{for all $(i,j)$} \tag2\label2 \\
-\alpha i - \beta j + 1 + \epsilon &\le M x_{ij} &&\text{for all $(i,j)$} \tag3\label3
\end{align}

Constraint \eqref{1} selects the top left corner.
Big-M constraint \eqref{2} enforces $x_{ij}=1 \implies \alpha i + \beta j \le 1 - \epsilon$ so that cell $(i,j)$ is on the same side of the line as $(0,0)$.
Big-M constraint \eqref{3} enforces $x_{ij}=0 \implies \alpha i + \beta j \ge 1 + \epsilon$ so that cell $(i,j)$ is on the opposite side of the line.

---

For the $100 \times 100$ instance (with total sum $\sum_{i,j} a_{ij}=316$), I get a maximum of $449$ by excluding the following cells with sum $-133$:
[image]

If I fix $x_{74,10}=x_{85,29}=x_{96,48}=1$ and $x_{74+1,10}=x_{85+1,29}=x_{96+1,48}=0$, I get a maximum of $440$ by excluding the following cells with sum $-124$:
[image]

If I fix $x_{74,10}=x_{85,29}=x_{96,48}=0$ and $x_{74-1,10}=x_{85-1,29}=x_{96-1,48}=1$, I get a maximum of $441$ by excluding the following cells with sum $-125$:
[image]

Comment: This is a very nice example of MILP.

Comment: If you scale the problem to 100 by 100 does your code still finish quickly?

Comment: @Simd That is 100x bigger, so probably not.  Do you have example data for that?

Comment: I will next be by a real computer in two days but I would make the data with numpy.random.randint(-3, 4, size=(100, 100)).

Comment: @Simd is this a new puzzle to post?

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't know if people will like it.  I was interested to see how quickly RobPratt's code could solve it.  Can you solve it yourself?  It looks like the paste has already done. I will redo it.

Comment: My first brutal C version took 55 minutes to solve my own random 100 grid. My current version takes under 2 minutes. I don't know if my answer for your pastebin data is correct.

Comment: Can you try https://paste.mozilla.org/jgC7NAMA ?

Comment: @WeatherVane Does it give the right answer for the 10 by 10 example in this question?

Comment: Yes. And my original brutal and newer versions agree for random grids 3 to 9 and 20, 30 and 35.

Comment: @Simd For your 100 by 100 instance, I got an optimal objective value of 449 in 36 minutes.

Comment: I got 454, from a line passing through (and excluding) the blobs at (row 74, col 10) and (row 85, col 29). Where (row 0 , col 0) would be the top left blob.

Comment: @RobPratt That is very interesting. I think it's quite a lot slower than you would get by coding up a fairly naive algorithm in a fast language.

Comment: @WeatherVane I get a max sum of 441, with 880 excluded and 9120 included, when I exclude those two points.  Do you get the same counts?

Comment: @Simd Big-M formulations are known to be weak, so it doesn't surprise me too much that it doesn't scale.

Comment: I don't have a cell count, I only sum their values. The line also passes through a third point (row 96, col 48), also excluded. I work on the assumption that the actual dividing line will be parallel to my line, excluding any blobs which lie on it. Tomorrow I'll try another test: parallel but including any blobs which lie on it. IOW the effective line is shifted slightly one way or the other of the blobs it connects.

Comment: I still get 441 when I exclude all three points.

Comment: I still get 454 when including the points passed through, but with a different line. And in doing so I have found (and posted) another solution to the 10x10 puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

I have found **two** solutions.

> Both solutions sum to 45. The sum of all the cells is 38.
>
>  I permuted a line connecting every pair of blobs.
>  I then consider a parallel dividing line moved slightly to one side.
>
>  First, blobs passed through are **excluded** from the black blob's region.
>  Excluded cells are (-3) + (-2) + (0) + (-2 -3) + (+2 +1) + (-1 +3 -2) = -7.
>  This is the same as other answers.
>  [image]
>
>  Then, blobs passed through are **included** with the black blob's region.
>  Excluded cells are (-1) + (-3) + (-2) + (0) + (-2) + (2) + (-1) = -7.
>  This is a new solution.
>  [image]

Comment: Very nice Indeed.

Comment: I confirmed that these are the only two optimal solutions.